# Excess logs debugging an android application

Tags: android, debugging, logging

Recently I earned a new android device - ZTE BLADE A520 on Android OS 7.0.
I connected it to adb via usb and launched my application. Then I see a lot of excess logs appearing in my android monitor dramatically fast and often.
This logs are interferes me to comfortable developing and debugging, so I want to get rid of them. Pls, tell me what can I do? Attaching a typical fragment of annoying logs:

```
    07-04 10:39:37.470 15873-15880/bz.molodost.fire I/art: Enter while loop.

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:37.482  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/stat


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:37.500  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=23, pid=18218

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:37.522  2011:18215 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18214) status=0000

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:37.529  2011:18219 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18218) status=0000
07-04 10:39:37.971 15873-15880/bz.molodost.fire I/art: Enter while loop.

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.040  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep 10183


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.043  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=23, pid=18220

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.058  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/15873/stat


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.061  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=24, pid=18222

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.079  2011:18225 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18222) status=0000

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.081  2011:18221 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18220) status=0000

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.094  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/stat


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.097  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=23, pid=18226

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.115  2011:18227 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18226) status=0000
07-04 10:39:38.471 15873-15880/bz.molodost.fire I/art: Enter while loop.

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.601  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep 10183


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.609  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=23, pid=18228

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.629  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/15873/stat


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.634  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=24, pid=18230

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.693  2011:18233 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18230) status=0000

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.697  2011:18229 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18228) status=0000

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.720  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       service_to_fd shell:cat /proc/stat


                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.723  2011: 2011 I/         ]
                                                       subprocess creation successful: local_socket_fd=23, pid=18234

                                                       [ 07-04 10:39:38.758  2011:18235 I/         ]
                                                       post waitpid (pid=18234) status=0000
```

I have a 5 another devices, but no one of them doesn't send me this excess logs

Comment: Right click on one of those logs, then you can configure logcat with strings to exclude from the outputs. Also, changing the log level (left of search) could filter them out.

Comment: (In extreme cases only) if filtering doesn't work out too well for you, and other methods don't go as planned, you may as well change the log level as @Alessio mentioned, and print your logcats in that level. Like 'Log.e' for the error filter